# I can't delete a directory inside a junctioned directory

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles, junction

So this is the deal. A couple of days ago I moved my profile folder `C:\Documents and Settings\fmunoz` to a different drive `D:\fmunoz`. Today, I created a directory in my desktop using the point-and-click method:

- Right-click on an empty space in the desktop
- Select `New`
- Select `Folder`
- Leave the default name `New Folder` and press `Enter`

I tried to delete the folder using the point-and-click method:

- Right-click the `New Folder` directory
- Select `Delete`

After five seconds, I got the following message:

```
---------------------------
Error Deleting File or Folder
---------------------------
Cannot delete New Folder: Access is denied.

Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected
and that the file is not currently in use.
---------------------------
```

Initially I thought that there must be some sort of indexing services locking the directory so I got a list of open files using the [*TuneUp Process Manager*](http://www.tune-up.com/) tool but the `New Folder` directory wasn't there.

I double-clicked **My Computer**, navigated to the desktop directory `C:\Documents and Settings\fmunoz\Destkop`, tried to delete the `New Folder` directory using the same point-and-click method described above and got exactly the same message at the same amount of time.

In the same window, I navigated to the actual location of the desktop directory `D:\fmunoz\Desktop`, tried to delete the `New Folder` directory and this time it worked.

I thought that this behavior was due to some special treatment that Windows gives to the desktop or the profile directories so I tried doing the same thing with a different set of directories:

- Created a folder `D:\dummy`
- Created a junction `C:\dummy` pointing to `D:\dummy`
- Created a `New Folder` directory in `C:\dummy`
- Tried to delete `New Folder` from `C:\dummy`. Didn't work.
- Tried to delete `New Folder` from `D:\dummy`. It worked.

I tried creating the folder in the actual directory rather than the junction directory:

- Created a `New Folder` directory in `D:\dummy`
- Tried to delete `New Folder` from `C:\dummy`. Didn't work.
- Tried to delete `New Folder` from `D:\dummy`. It worked.

I also tried using the `Delete` button instead of using the `Delete` option of the context menu but it didn't work.

When using the `Shift+Delete` sequence, it works. It also works by using the `rd` command in the console, but in both cases the deleted directory doesn't goes to the Recycle Bin, which is my intention when using the `Delete` context menu option or the `Delete` button.

Comment: Try right clicking the file, select `properties` and then the security tab.Then select `edit` and make sure the account you're logged in with has "full" permissions.

Comment: Thanks @ben-plont, I tried checking the security settings as you suggested and they seemed to be OK. I also tried to give `Full Control` permissions to the group `Everyone` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Windows XP when moved the "Documents and Settings" folder to another disk and made the Junction, to solve it I booted from one XP live CD and deleted the folders "RECYCLER" from the disk where the junction was created, I suppose C: where is Windows XP installed and D: where "Documents and Settings" was moved, then created a junction using:

```
rmdir /S C:\RECYCLER 
MKLINK /J C:\RECYCLER D:\RECYCLER 
attrib C:\RECYCLER +s +h
```

I Hope that can help you.

JB